# adapting X86 Directory structure for X64 system in WIX

Tags: wix, 32bit-64bit, windows-7-x64

I am having a problem to get the WIX installer to detect if it is running on a X86 or X64 operating system. it needs to detect it since the directory structure needs some small adaptations. however the code I use generated the following error:

There was no XML start tag open.

the code I use:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="WindowsVolume">
    <Directory Id="Data" Name="Data" />
    <Directory Id="wheels" Name="wheels"/>

    <?if $(sys.BUILDARCH)=x64?>
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder(x86)">
    <?else?>
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <?endif?>

        <Directory Id="ActiveXControlPad" Name="ActiveX Control Pad" >
          <Directory Id="Setup" Name="Setup"/>
          <Directory Id="Refdocs" Name="Refdocs" />
        </Directory>
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="HM Machine Software" />
        <Directory Id="SPOKE" Name="SPOKE" />
        <Directory Id="MMI" Name="MMI" >
          <Directory Id="images" Name="images" />
        </Directory>
        <Directory Id="CommonFilesFolder" Name="CommonFilesFolder">
          <Directory Id="microsoftShared" Name="microsoft shared">
            <Directory Id="DAO" Name="DAO" />
            <Directory Id="SystemFolder">
            </Directory>
          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

I am trying to use the If statement to detect the build architecture and adapt the ProgramFilesFolder accordingly. because when it detect X64 it should adapt the directory to ProgramFiles(x86) and the following directorys in that structure should be placed from there.

what is it I am doing wrong? I dont need a flexible solution for it. it just needs to detect x86/x64 and act accordingly.

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you expect this part to generate one open Directory element:

```
<?if $(sys.BUILDARCH)=x64?>
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder(x86)">
<?else?>
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
<?endif?>
```

However, [processing instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_Instruction) for WiX do not work like the C preprocessor, so your elements still need to be balanced for the XML to be valid. When processing the XML, WiX will ignore things on one side of your conditional. I've seen people [`<?define ?>`](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/preprocessor.html) a variable one of two ways, then reference that variable in a single non-conditional `Directory` element.

Comment: why is everything always more difficult in wix. it is getting real annoying real fast. anayway, what am i supposed to define? something like <? define PlatformProgramFilesFolder = "Program Files (x86)"?>  ?? and how can i reference it to an directory element? i already have been trying thing out bud it just doesn't work.

Comment: i seem to have the reference working however it always chooses the wrong one ( the one for 32bit). so i think it isn't reading the system variable that detects if it is a 64bit operating system. any suggestions?